# my submit button not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

http://investinlisbon.ml/
So i've my little form on top of the page (button call me back!), but my submit button (Send) stopped working

I'm guessing my function is maybe overrinding my form?

JS

```
$('#cmb-button').toggle(function() {
//this will happen when your mouse moves over the object
$('#cmb-button2').css({
"display": "none"
});
$('#cmb-button3').css({
"display": "inline"
});

}, function() {
//this is what will happen when you take your mouse off the object
$('#1101').css({});
});
```

PHP

```
<div id="cmb-button" class="cmb">

<div id="cmb-button2">

<button type="button" id="buttoncontact">
  Call me back!
</button>

</div>

<div id="cmb-button3">
<?php 
 echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7        id="1101" title="Call Back PT"]' );
                            ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#1101')` *Hm...*. I don't think CSS IDs can be completely numeric or start with a numerical value.

Comment: Yea, i'll change that, but that's not its causing the problem, i've changed i several times aldready.

Comment: If it's a PHP problem, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - And/or if it's a JS issue, check your console and make sure the jQuery library is loaded. Look at you HTML source and use var_dump().

Comment: In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); ***they cannot start with a digit***, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Comment: One thing I will mention is that your usage of .toggle() has been deprecated since jQuery v1.8 and officially removed as of v1.9. If you are using a newer version of jQuery, you might be experiencing difficulties as a result.

Comment: @mhodges That was exactly the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @PedroBronze No problem!

Comment: and your console would have most likely shown you something about it. Something I told you to check up there.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yea, thank you for the help aswell !

Answer (score 1):

The issue causing your code to break is that your usage of `.toggle()` has been deprecated since jQuery v1.8 and officially removed as of v1.9. If you are using a newer version of jQuery, you might be experiencing difficulties as a result.

**Deprecated**: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

**New**: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/